# Let p be a prime number and n an integer such that 1 ≤ n ≤ p. Show that $(p-n)!(n-1)! \equiv (-1)^{n} \mod p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

> Let p be a prime number and n an integer such that 1 ≤ n ≤ p. Show that.

$$(p-n)!(n-1)! ≡ (-1)^n\mod p.$$

> I know it's related to Wilson's theorem ( If p is a prime number, then (p - 1)! ≡ -1 (mod p)) but I don't know, how to prove it?

Comment: The question is wrong. it should be mod $p$ instead of mod $n$. In any case, please show some of your own efforts (even just write down the correct statement of Wilson's theorem, which should already be halfway toward the answer).

Comment: HINT: Recall that $k\equiv-(p-k)\pmod p$ for $1\le k\le p-1$. Focus on $1\le k\le n-1$.

Answer (score 2):

By Wilson´s theorem, $(p-1)!≡-1 \mod p$. That is, $(p-1)(p-2)\dots n(n-1)!≡-1 \mod p$. Now using the $p-n$ congruences modulo $p$

$p-1≡-1$;

$p-2≡-2$;

$\dots$;

$n≡p-(p-n)≡-(p-n)$;

we can substitute in the previous equality and, we obtain$(-1)\cdot(-2)\dots(-(p-n))(n-1)!≡-1 \mod p$, or equivalently,

$(-1)^{(p-n)}(p-n)!(n-1)!≡-1 \mod p$.

This is the same equality as the one in the problem, using that $p$ is odd.